# Using www as hostname on a server running apache and exim?

Tags: web-server, exim, hostname

I have a VPS that is currently hosting a website and also serves as a mail server running `exim`. I own a SSL certificate for `website.com` which also works for `www.website.com`.

Since my server's FQDN is `server.website.com` I cannot make use of my certificate for emails, so I was wondering if it was a good idea to change my hostname to `www.website.com`?

I was pretty confident that it was a good idea... until I found this on WHM:

> Hostnames should never begin with “www”

Is this definitely a no no? Would it be better to do a custom hostname configuration for exim?

Is it even reasonable to name a mail server as `www.something.com`?

Answer (score 1):

A single server can have multiple names. It can be achieved by a proper configuration of Domain Name Server.

Just add additional 'A' or 'CNAME' entries in your DNS Server pointing to the IP Address or the main name of your server respectively.

In my case I put some fictional names on the servers and on the 'PTR' register and create a lot of 'CNAME's with the desired public available name.

And yes, you can have multiple certificates on the same machine covering all the names you want to use.